# Some Youtube shared videos in facebook open in YT app and others open in FB web popup

Tags: facebook, youtube, ios-universal-links

I stumbled over this today and it seems I won't be able to sleep unless I figured out why this is happening.

I have two youtube videos URL's (both viedos are from the same channel), the URLs was in below format:

```
https://youtu.be/_VID_
```

Then I opened Facebook and shared each video separately in a post. both posts ONLY contains the URL, and of course the preview that facebook automatically adds.

Now using facebbok app on my iPhone, I opened a video, facbook opened it via facebook web popup.
the other video always open in youtube app.
I tried opening both videos from another smartphone, I got the same result.

So it seems that facebook app have some sort of algorithm that decide if a link will be opened in a web popup or using Universal Links through the related app.

Does anyone know how facebook decide when to open app or simply pop it in a web view?